# Can a Druid use Conjure Animals to conjure a new creature and then Wild Shape into it?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

For example, let's say I have a level 8 Druid who has never seen a Quasit before, and I use the spell Conjure Animals to conjure 2 Quasits. On my next action, may I use my Wild Shape to change into a Quasit?